# How do I initialize an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to declare an `Array` of `Rectangles` in java but I can't figure out how. Here is my code:

```
private Rectangle rectArray[] = new Rectangle[9];
rectArray[0] = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
```

I tried commenting out the second line and it works fine, but when I leave the second line in, it has the error:

```
Syntax error on token ";" expected {
```

It's not declaring the `Array` that's the problem; initializing it is the problem. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Would you rather do the initialisation inside a method, or inside the constructor of whatever class this is?  It is possible to do it as an "initialisation block" by enclosing your second line in `{ }` characters, but it's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Are you saying i should initialize the rectangles inside the class constructer?

Comment: It's hard to say what you "should" do, without knowing what you're actually trying to build here.  But it would help you over the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Rectangle rectArray[] = new Rectangle[9];
rectArray[0] = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
```

You have to initialize within constructor (generally constructor (or even initilisation block) than method for init).
In your case, you mixed field (as suggested by your `private` keyword) with computation, leading to the compilation error you got.

You may want to do:

```
MyClass {

     private Rectangle rectArray[] = new Rectangle[9];

     MyClass() {
      rectArray[0] = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);
     }
   }
```

Comment: wait i'm confused can you explain it a little better? What is different between my code and yours?

Comment: `private` is used for annotating an object's field, not a local variable. You cannot write some "process" directly on the class. You have to wrap it in a constructor, initialisation block or method. Indeed, this line: `rectArray[0] = new Rectangle(0,0,0,0);` is what I called a "process", since you use data (the array) your initialized. All the init process concerning a field should be inlined, that is not your case.

Comment: "Why cant youn initialize outside a method or constructor?" => that's how Java was designed by its creator.

Comment: I would use `Rectangle[] var = ` instead of `Rectangle var[]`. It makes it clear that it's an array of `Rectangle` objects.